# How to call method from parent when i click on child?

Tags: angular

I have two components, parent and child. In child i have button. I want when user click on that button in child to call method that is in parent. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very basic angular, and you will find plenty of examples through the guides on https://angular.io.

But if you still could not find it, you have to use the `@Output` decorator, set an `EventEmitter` field to it and call `emit` when the button is clicked. This way you can attach to it from your parent using the event notation `()`:

**parent**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   template: `<child (buttonClick)="onButtonClick($event)"></child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

   public onButtonClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
      // ...
   }

}
```

**child**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `<button (click)="buttonClick.emit($event)"></button>`
})
export class ChildComponent {

   @Output()
   public buttonClick: EventEmitter<MouseEvent> = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

}
```